# React Horizontal Smooth Scroll

Tags: reactjs, horizontal-scrolling, smooth-scrolling

This is such a vague question because I'm struggling to find a solution-

can anyone recommend a package or technique for a horizontal smooth scroll in React- NOT Native?

(it will be the whole body of the app, not a menu)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [react-smooth-scroll-hook](https://github.com/ron0115/react-smooth-scroll-hook), it use `requestAnimationFrame` to finish scroll behaviour.

Basic usage below

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import useSmoothScroll from 'react-smooth-scroll-hook';
export const Demo = () => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const { scrollTo } = useSmoothScroll({
    ref,
    speed: 100,
    direction: 'y',
  });

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => scrollTo('#item-20')}>scrollTo('#item-20')</button>
      <div
        ref={ref}
        style={{
          overflowY: 'scroll',
          maxHeight: '200px',
        }}
      >
        {Array(100)
          .fill(null)
          .map((_item, i) => (
            <div key={i} id={`item-${i}`}>
              item-{i}
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: This looks like this is your own project. Please read [our requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), you **must** disclose your connection.